# how do I link a sass stylesheet to rails templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

This is a newb question, I know, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've been using rails for a while but always went with regular css. Not sure if I'm supposed to use

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style' %>
```

I store my sass file in `public/stylesheets/sass/style.sass`, and did the whole

`$ sass --rails /path/to/app`

thing.

Oh, I'm trying it with rails-3 beta 2 and haml 3b2. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, forgot to restart the development server :)